Unable to Run GUI Applications (rviz, gazebo) in ROS2 Humble Docker Container on Ubuntu 24.04 - "qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0"
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and am running a Docker container with a ROS2 Humble image. While most functionality works fine, I encounter an error when trying to run GUI applications like rviz or gazebo:
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb. Aborted
Steps I've Tried:

Ran xhost +local:root on the host machine.
Verified display settings.
Installed required libraries using:

sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0
sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xfixes0 libegl1-mesa
Despite these efforts, the error persists. As I'm relatively new to Linux, any guidance or advice on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
